# Don't let NGINX reset established connection if upstream down

Tags: nginx, tcp, smtp, postfix-mta

I'm trying to perform a graceful restart of my smtp backends in order to accept all of incoming emails: I close the listening socket on the backend side while keeping opened connections alive.

I hoped that NGINX would let the existing connections to finish, but pass all of the new ones to the second available backend. But what I see in the logs of postfix sending emails to NGINX is that NGINX resets all of the established connections ones it notices backend closed listening on its address.

Is my guess correct and if it is how can I make NGINX behave like I wanted it to behave: pass all new connections to another backend, but don't interrupt already established ones?

Here is my NGINX stream configuration.

```
upstream smtp {
    server 127.0.0.1:1025 fail_timeout=0;
    server 127.0.0.1:1026 fail_timeout=0;

    server 127.0.0.1:1025 backup;
}


server {
    listen       25 reuseport;
    proxy_pass   smtp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the NGINX "down" marker?

You will need to modify your NGINX conf twice each time you want to restart one of your SMTP backend but at least you have zero downtime!

So before restarting one backend, mark its upstream server as "down" like this:

```
upstream smtp {
    server 127.0.0.1:1025 down;
    server 127.0.0.1:1026;
}

server {
    listen       25 reuseport;
    proxy_pass   smtp;
}
```

Then you need to reload the NGINX config file with **service ngnix reload** or **nginx -s reload**

At this point NGINX should not send any new connection on the port 1025 and also don't drop any existing connection either. So now you cant restart your backend.

After that, you can remove the "down" marker and reload the NGINX config again.

PS: I never try this method but I'm very curious to know if it works